# How do I change the base URL to use a more user-friendly domain?

Tags: uri

I want to change my domain name from reallylongandnotuserfriendly.example.com to you.example.com.

Is there a setting that could expose these change to the public, without actually changing the real domain name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a Drupal alias as follows:

1. In the *sites* directory, find and rename the example.sites.php file to sites.php
2. Add the following line

   ```
   $sites['you.example.com'] = 'name_of_the_directory_where_your_settings.php_is';
   ```

In your case, the settings.php file is likely to be inside *sites* in a directory called *reallylongandnotuserfriendly.example.com*, which means the line would be:

```
$site['you.example.com'] = 'reallylongandnotuserfriendly.example.com';
```

Just be sure that you configure your server to point you.example.com to your base Drupal installation.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the setting.php file
2. Find `$base_url` in that file
3. Change the value of `$base_url`

change the file permissions for that file, since by default it is a read-only file.

Comment: Isn't that actually changing the domain name? Or is it just "redirecting"?

Comment: you asking change base url.can you explain little more ??

Comment: I am looking for an easy way to change the display of links, without actually changing anything. Meaning that both old.example.com and new.example.com would go to the same place, but only new.example.com is exposed

Comment: then you need to create custom module for that

Comment: Sorry that it is unclear, but that was sort of what I thought I was asking about...